# Как сделать рассылку сообщения в телеграмм боте aiogram?

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram, бот

Пытаюсь сделать рассылку сообщения подписчикам телеграм-бота. 
Как сделать так, чтобы отправлялось сообщение, набранное с клавиатуры?

```
@dp.message_handler(text='/special')
async def notify_users(message: types.Message):
    user_list=[1,2,3]
    for user_id in user_list:
        await bot.send_message(user_id, 'ало')
```

Comment: ну и в чем проблема то ?

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin 
@dp.message_handler(text='/special')
async def notify_users(message: types.Message):
    user_list=[]
    for user_id in user_list:
      await bot.send_message(user_id,message.text[message.text.find(' '):])

При таком коде бот не отправляет набранное сообщение  с клавиатуры

Comment: а в user_list реальные id пользователей,

Answer (score 0):

Решилось таким спообом

```
@dp.message_handler(Command('sendall'))
async def send_all(message: Message):
    if message.chat.id==admins_id:
        
        await message.answer("Start")
        
        for i in users:
            await bot.send_message(i,message.text[message.text.find(' '):])
        await message.answer('Done')

    else:
        await message.answer('Error')
```

Answer (score 0):

Так рассылку будет легче использовать, потому что идёт ещё запись ID пользователей бот в отдельный документ joined.txt, который нужно создать самому.

```py
joinedFile = open("joined.txt", "r")
joinedUsers = set ()
for line in joinedFile:
    joinedUsers.add(line.strip())
joinedFile.close()

@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def startjoin(message):
    if not str(message.chat.id) in joinedUsers:
        joinedFile = open("joined.txt", "a")
        joinedFile.write(str(message.chat.id) + "\n")
        joinedUsers.add(message.chat.id)

@dp.message_handler(commands=['sendall'])
async def mess(message: types.Message):
    for user in joinedUsers:
        await dp.bot.send_message(chat_id = user,text=message.text[message.text.find(' '):])
```